# VSTO Outlook Deployment - ClickOnce

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have written a very simple add-in that adds a button to the ribbon of outlook (C#).

I have spent days trying to get this very simple add-in to install on another machine using the clickonce method.

I have published clickonce to ftp using Visual Studio. All fine so far.

Upon running the resulting vsto (or setup.exe) on a different machine I am getting the error:

> 'System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for  Add-In or its location is not trusted. Contact your administrator for further assistance.'

I understand the idea behind a certificate being required to remove rogue add-ins being added to Outlook. I have signed the clickonce deployment using a test certificate on my machine.

Simply is it possible, without paying for a third-party certificate, to give a user the clickonce url and them install it without me having to do anything to their machine? (and/or domain etc.) This is ideally to be used by lots of enterprise users. Altering their environment isn't practical.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your certificate chain.  Most likely you need to place a copy of the certificate into:

**Certificates - Current User\Trusted Root Certification Authorities**

...so your "issuer" is trusted in order for your certificate to be trusted.

Comment: Is there a way to make ClickOnce installer put the certificate there automatically?

Comment: @ALazyDoe No, that would be a security risk

Comment: So there is no way to enable the user to install VSTO without buying a certificate or forcing the user to install the certificate himself?

Comment: No way to somehow automatically display a trust popup request or something similar to enable a fluid installation either?

Comment: @ALazyDoe asking the same question in slightly different ways will not result in a different outcome

Comment: I'm asking because I am pretty sure I didn't have to install the cert manually on my test clients' pc and all I had to do to make it work was to hit Unblock in my .vsto files' properties.